# Why in this MYSQL query WHERE clause is ignored?

Tags: php, mysql, count, where-clause, rows

I am trying to make this to count table's rows which have specific category, but it doesn't seem to work. It always returns total amount of rows in the table, so I came to conclusion, that WHERE clause is simply ignored... Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
  $c = $_GET['c'];  
  $max = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news_posts WHERE Category = '".mysql_real_escape_string($c)."'")); 
  $max = $max[0];
```

Tried the same query on the database, there it works as it should.

$c value is either "Other", or "Articles". In both cases it returns 15 - the total amount of rows in that table.

---

### SOLVED, thank you all...

---

Comment: what is the value of $c?

Comment: Did you tried the same query on the database? Maybe you have only registers on that Category

Comment: have you check $c has value?

Comment: Remove the count(*) and print the data to see if the category is ignored

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the result from the array. Use the following code:

```
$c = $_GET['c'];  
  $maxquery = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news_posts WHERE Category = '$c'"); 
$maxfetch=mysql_fetch_array($maxquery);
  $max = $maxfetch[0];
```